# Get token from paypal express checkout

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

How can i integrate with my website woocommerce and get token EC-xxxx on server side . I described in https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/upgrade-integration/ and try to fetch but can't . Thank in advance

Comment: Please don't rely on external sources only to describe your problem. Show the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Use the WooCommerce PayPal Payments plugin. It gets a token from the server side. It's already implemented. https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-paypal-payments/